# How does Go decide when to context switch between goroutines?

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

I am curious as to how the Go language schedules goroutines. Does it switch only during channel requests and I/O or does it have a periodic coroutine switching loop?

Answer (score 8):

Go does not have a preemptive scheduler yet, but one is [planned for 1.2](http://dominik.honnef.co/go-tip/2013-08-15/). So no, Go will not switch context during CPU-only calculations, only during I/O (reading from memory is also considered I/O if it isn't in a register already). You can read some discussion about it in [Issue 543 - preemptive scheduling](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=543).

Comment: If I understand correctly, calling what is described on these links 'preemptive scheduling' is too far-fetched. It is not really preemptive, it is just that yields are put in more places, invisibly to the programmer. Sure, that makes the program more 'concurrent', but it is still cooperative. I think it is impossible to do preemptive multitasking without using special VM (like Erlang) or without direct OS support (OS threads).

Comment: Could you please update your answer? I've heard that Go has been able to pre-empt at function calls for a while now, but I don't know for sure.