# How implement go style channels (CSP) with objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, go, yield, channel

I wonder how create a [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) library for obj-c, that work like [Go](http://golang.org)'s channels/goroutines but with idiomatic obj-c (and less boilerplate than actual ways).

In other languages with native courutines and/or generators is possible to model it easily, but I don't grasp how do the same with the several ways of do concurrent programing in obj-c (plus, the idea is have "cheap" threads).

Any hint about what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [State Threads library](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net/) as it implements roughly the same idea which underlies the goroutine switching algorythm of Go: a goroutine surrenders control to the scheduler when it's about to sleep in a syscall, and so the ST library wraps OS-level file descriptors to provide their own FD-like objects which can be read from (and/or written to) but instead of blocking the whole process these operation transfer control to other light-weight threads managed by the library.

Then you might need a scheduler more advanced than that of the ST library to keep OS threads busy running your SPs. A no-brainer introduction to the Go 1.2 scheduler is [here](http://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler), and it contains a link to a more hard-core design document.  The rest is in the Go's source code.

See also [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18545625/720999).

Comment: I could use a C library, but the question is about how do the same in obj-c

Comment: @mamcx, I'm not suggesting to use a C library, I suggest *studying how it works.*

Comment: The Objective-C runtime maintains a (private) shadow stack for the autorelease pools, so be very wary of attempting any stack shenanigans when Objective-C code is involved. If you switch the stack context, you'll need to make sure this is safe WRT the autorelease pool stack. Unfortunately, the way the autorelease pool stack is maintained is not a stable ABI, so Apple can change it without notice, which makes shipping Apps that mess with the stack pretty risky.

Answer (score 0):

Create operations, e.g. for an example consider this process:

- *process `x` takes number from `east`, transforms it to a string, and gives it to `west`.*

That I could model it with an object that keeps an internal state of `x` (consisting of number and string) and the following operations:

- `east-output`, operation defined somewhere else by `east` process logic
- `x-input`, operation that depends on `east-output`. It copies number from `east-output`'s data structure into `x`'s data structure
- `x-output`, operation that depends on `x-input`. Its content is defined as purely internal transformation - in our example, `stringWithFormat...`
- `west-input`, operation that depends on `x-output`, etc.

Then you dump the operations into `NSOperationQueue` and see what happens (does it work, or are there contradicting dependencies...)

Comment: Model the object is not the hard part. Obj-c have not YIELD support, neither coroutines, so I don't know how "wait" and/or do a SELECT in the channels. Obj-c have blocks and some higher level APIs but are more for callback-style one-shot background task, and I can't grasp how turn them in general purpose, for hundreds of task, async/closure/channel/select/scheduling stuff. I know how derive CSP from YIELD, but the one YIELD for obj-c I know is a huge hack. However I suspect must be possible with blocks...

Comment: I wanted to give a talk about this for years. Blocks are no solution per se, because they have *nothing* to do with concurrency, but with closures. (Okay, closures are a good tool *for* concurrency, but are not a tool *of* concurrency.) You can do something like this with GCD. Anyway there is a sample for the generator-comsumer-pattern in the talks about GCD on the WWDC 2012(?).

Comment: Ok, then how do this with GCD?

Comment: @Amin: I say, closures are blocks, concurrency is `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: @mamcx As I said, there is sample code on a WWDC video. I would have to search it as you.

Comment: @ilya, yes, I would say it the same way adding GCD.